# Insert into List when list Count is "0"

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, generic-list

here is my code

```
public class ControlProperty
{        
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ControlProperty ct = new ControlProperty();
        ControlProperty ct1 = new ControlProperty();
        List<ControlProperty> lstct = new List<ControlProperty>();
        ct.DisplayName = "test";
        ct1.DisplayName = "test1";
        ct1.SortOrder = 1;
        ct.SortOrder = 0;
        lstct.Insert(ct1.SortOrder, ct1);
        lstct.Insert(ct.SortOrder, ct);
        lstbxIncidentControls.ItemsSource = lstct;

    }
}
```

here im trying to insert a list (according to the sortorder) item into a list object for which count is zero and which cannot be inserted like that....

so i want to insert into the list according to my sort order....

can any one help me on this

Comment: list.add dude. use the add method.

Comment: if you use `Insert` the first parameter is the index in the list you want to position it. You can't use `SortOrder` because that hasn't got anything to do with the index in the list

Comment: @EdPlunkett unnecessarily sarcastic

Comment: I enjoyed the sarcasm, its the only reason i gave an answer it made me laugh so I had enough happiness to answer such a stupid question XD

Comment: @JayMEE While unnecessary, it was quite hilarious.

Comment: Hilarious? Are we talking about the same comment?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `.Add` function of a list

```
List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
mylist.Add("firstvalue");
mylist.Add("secondvalue");

string getsecondvalue = mylist[1];//remember it starts at 0 so the first entry is mylist[0]
```

This is an example of how to use the `.Insert` function
i.e this will work if the list has no values inserted(`mylist.Count` = 0)

```
mylist.Insert(0, "inserted");
```

if however your list has no values (`mylist.Count` = 0) and you try

```
mylist.Insert(1, "inserted");
```

It would break because it has no value to add in position 0

If however there was data in `mylist` it would insert it in position 1 (As specified)
and move the rest one up i.e `1->2` ,`2->3` ,`3->4` and so on

Answer (score 0):

add a wrapper function with a condition that if the index is higher then size of List, it will be added at the end of it.

```
  public static void OrderIndex(List<ControlProperty> lControlProperty, ControlProperty controlProperty, int index)
    {
        if (lControlProperty.Count < index)
        {
            lControlProperty.Add(controlProperty);
        }
        else
        {
            lControlProperty.Insert(index, controlProperty);
        }
    }
```

Call it like this:

```
 OrderIndex(lstct, ct1, ct1.SortOrder);
 OrderIndex(lstct, ct, ct.SortOrder);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a List of ControlProperty

```
lstct.Add(ct);  
lstct.Add(ct1);
```

Or cleaner

```
public class ControlProperty
{        
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public ControlProperty (int sortOrder, string displayName) 
    {
        SortOrder = sortOrder;
        DisplayName = displayName;
    }
}

lstct.Add(new ControlProperty(0, "text0");
lstct.Add(new ControlProperty(1, "text1");
```